# read 1/2/5 string inputs in c

Tags: c, string, input

i need to read input from the standart input line by line

but each line will contain 1 or 2 or 5 strings like :

```
bofob fbo
blabla bibi bobo fbo fbooo
bobobo bobo 
bobof
```

how can i do this?

my idea is really not looking profassional and not working

```
char a[50],b[50],c[50],d[50],f[50];
int numOfStrings=0;
scanf(" %s",a);    char a[50],b[50],c[50],d[50],f[50];
int numOfStrings=0;
scanf(" %s",a);
if (scanf (" %s",b)){
   numOfStrings=2;
   if (scanf (" %s %d %d",c,d,f)
      numOfStrings=5;
    }
if (scanf (" %s",b)){
   numOfStrings=2;
   if (scanf (" %s %d %d",c,d,f)
      numOfStrings=5;
    }
```

but its not working because it goes and read inputs from the next line

is there a way to read a whole line (i know its max 250 chars) and then know how many words are in there?

edit:
i will add a count words function
but what is the nicest wat ro read a line untilll the end line or eof??

```
int words(const char *sentence)
{
    int count,i,len;
    char lastC;
    len=strlen(sentence);
    if(len > 0)
    {
        lastC = sentence[0];
    }
    for(i=0; i<=len; i++)
    {
        if(sentence[i]==' ' && lastC != ' ')
        {
            count++;
        }
        lastC = int words(const char *sentence)
}


    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `fgets()` to take the input *line-by-line*. check the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). It will also liberate you from handling the limitation of [1/2/5/.....] `number`s of *space-seperated* strings. Provided sufficient storage, you can read `1 to any` number of "string"s.

Note: You might need to take care of the trailing newline `\n` [caused by <kbd>ENTER</kbd>] yourself. Causes trouble most of the times.

Answer (score 2):

You could scan one line until the '\n' with `%[^\n]`, then split the line into words with `strtok()`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char s[2] = " ";
const int MAX_LINE_SIZE = 128;
FILE *fp; 
char *word, *str;
int word_counter;

/* Open the file here */    

while (fgets(str, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fp) != NULL) 
{
    word_counter = 0
    /* get the first word */
    word = strtok(str, s);

    /* walk through other words */
    while (word != NULL) 
    {
       printf(" %s\n", word);
       word_counter++; 

       word = strtok(NULL, s);
    }

    printf("This string contains %d words\n",word_counter);

} 

/* END of FILE */
```

Comment: how can i know when i get to the end of file?

Comment: yes but if i send a file from the standart input, how will it know its finished without /n?

Comment: In that case, use fgets on the file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgets` to read a file and `strchr` to count the number of spaces:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[250];
    char *p;
    FILE *f;
    int i;

    f = fopen("demo.txt", "r");
    while ((p = fgets(s, sizeof s, f))) {
        i = 0;
        while ((p = strchr(p, ' '))) {
            p++;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d spaces\n", i);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```